# IPhone Image Caching

Tags: iphone

I want to save images fetched from a url into the NSTempDirectory(). If I store more than 100 images the application gets slow and sometimes quits.  How many images can be stored in NSTempDirectory()?  Would deleting the files continuously after it reaches 50 or more images be a good solution?  Is there any other alternative to store images without affecting the application performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Clawoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469418/iphone-image-caching/8703459#answer-5469767) is right. Check your memory management and do one more thing.

You can add your code for deleting data from temp directory inside this function: `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

This function is called whenever you receive memory warning error.

Answer (score 0):

If the application becomes sluggish the problem lies in your memory management implementation. Make sure you release all your objects, especially the ones that you use to download the images (NSURLConnections, NSData, UIImage, etc).

Writing all those images to disk (whether it's a temp directory or not doesn't really matter) should NOT impact your application's performance in the long term, let alone outright kill it. The application is being shut down because it most probably runs out of memory.